# Dynamically apply a common dependent gradle file?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle file (common-utils.gradle) with a bunch of useful functions common across various projects. I've got that file in Artifactory. Now, I want my project's build.gradle to pull down that common-utils.gradle file and "apply from: 'common-utils.gradle'" so I can then use those utility methods.

Is there a way to do that dynamically, so the first time I run "gradle test" it fetches this common file and applies it? Or do I have to have some sort of one time "init" task I run after I clone the repository to go fetch the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well the easiest way to apply a *.gradle file you already have in artifactory is to reference this remote file in the apply from method:

```
apply from:'http://yourartifactory/repo/path/to/1.0/common-utils.gradle'
```

one downside of this is, that gradle does not cache this file atm. It will resolve it with every single gradle invocation. There is an open issue listed for that in the gradle issue tracker. you can vote for caching at http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-835

cheers,
René